# Python regex multiple matching groups

Tags: python, regex

I am using a small utility to find the type a file under Windows.

```
TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.10 - (C) 2003-11 
By M.Pontello Definitions found:  5295  Analyzing... 

Collecting data from file: april_error.wmv

94.1% (.WMV/WMA) Windows Media (generic) (16018/6)
 5.8% (.CAT) Microsoft Security Catalog (1000/1)
```

In Python, how can I capture the `(.WMV/WMA)` cause it seems that I currently get a wrong matching group.
For instance `re.search('\((.*?)\)', stdout).group(1)` returns `'C'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want to capture this: `(.WMV/WMA)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `findall` instead:

```
a = re.findall('\((.*?)\)', stdout)

>>> print a
['C','.WMV/WMA','generic','16018/6','.CAT','1000/1']

>>> print a[1]
.WMV/WMA
```

Or as @tobias_k suggested, do the following to only capture the file extension matches:

```
a = re.findall('\((\..*?)\)', stdout)

>>> print a
['.WMV/WMA', '.CAT']
```

Comment: +1 Maybe add a `\.` to find only the groups with actual file extensions.

Comment: @sshashank124 I believe you've got to cut out the `.group` part cause I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @sshashank124 Yes. It does. Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 5'.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment above, this is what you need:

```
match = re.search(r"% \([a-z.]+/[a-z.]+\)", subject, re.IGNORECASE)
```